# Updating a MySql Database in C# Rapidly

Tags: c#, mysql, performance

I am trying to write a text-based game similar to popular browser games (ogame,ikariam,tribalwars) using C# and a MySql database. For this I will have a server updating the users' accounts in the database every second and also users accessing the database to get information and play. However, I've problems with the speed the database is updating. For example, I wrote following code to check the online status and the activity of the user and to update the database. But it takes 400ms-1000ms to do it every time with only 3 users and increases as I add users. I will do a lot more updating and will have much more users. This is what I get in the admin panel I wrote:
http://s27.postimg.org/hbg39icib/panel.png

```
private void serverRunner_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ArrayList lastonline = new ArrayList();
        int users = 0, active = 0, onlines = 0;

        MySqlCommand getUsers = new MySqlCommand("SELECT lastonline FROM sql435127.members", c);
        MySqlDataReader Reader = getUsers.ExecuteReader();

        while (Reader.Read())
            lastonline.Add(DateTime.Parse(Reader["lastonline"].ToString()));
        Reader.Close();

        users = lastonline.Count;
        int k = 0;
        int[] activity= new int[users];
        int[] onlinestatus = new int[users];

        foreach(DateTime date in lastonline)
        {
            int value1 = DateTime.Compare(date, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-5));
            int value2 = DateTime.Compare(date, DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7));

            if (value1 <= 0)
                onlinestatus[k] = 0;
            else
            {
                onlinestatus[k] = 1;
                onlines++;
            }


            if (value2 <= 0)
                activity[k] = 0;
            else
            {
                activity[k] = 1;
                active++;
            }

            k++;
            MySqlCommand updateUser = new MySqlCommand("Update sql435127.members SET activity = '" + activity[k-1] + "', online = '"+ onlinestatus[k-1] + "' WHERE id = '" + k + " '", c);
            updateUser.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
```

(This is part of the code. I declare the connection outside the method to save time and I also have a timer in this method)

I am supposed to be updating 3000 rows in maybe 50 ms. Instead I am updating 3 rows in 500ms.

My Question is: Why is this connection so slow and how can I fix it?
Reasons I can think:

1. The way I'm updating the database

   - I don't know what other methods or queries I can use in C# to improve the performance.
2. That I'm using C#

   - Should I use a serverside language like PHP instead of connecting from another computer
3. Slow Internet Speed

   - My internet is relatively slow but I don't think this is the major problem
4. Slow Database (I'm using a free host)

   - I created this database from a free host. I can buy paid host service. But should I?
5. Other Reasons

   - If you think I can do this in C# using a free MySql database with a slow internet from another computer, what do you think is the major problem?

Comment: Not exactly to answer your question but it is recommended to add parameters to the command instead of concatenating them into the string raw like that. Also, C# is not going to be the cause of your performance issues.

Comment: Stored procedures run faster than normal queries, try with stored procedure, and yes, C# has nothing to do with this slowness as I dont see any such issue in the code, so the delay is really coming from DB side

Comment: By stored procedures, do you mean the ones that are stored in the database? Can that significantly improve the performance ?

Comment: Writing state to the database _could_ be reasonable if you only write actual changes, but reading everything for every user from there is probably not. Caching should at the very least improve things significantly.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of problems here:

`SELECT lastonline FROM sql435127.members` will return rows with no guaranteed order, but later on, you use an index `k` to update by `id`.  With only 3 users, the rows will be returned in order 1,2,3 but when you get thousands of members, this is not guaranteed.

You're updating two fields every second with values calculated from `lastonline`. You don't need to do this.  Whenever you want to use these fields, just select `lastonline` and calculate the current value.  This is actually a common solution to many performance problems; if X is too slow, see if you really need to do X, rather than trying to make it faster.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to answer your reason whether they are correct or not.

### 1.The way I'm updating the database

Surely, this might be the reason, because you're updating the server on the `Tick` event

### 2.That I'm using C#

No matter what language you are using, database latency isn't because of usage of language.

### 3.Slow Internet Speed

This has really nothing to do with your problem. The time taken is from server side.

### 4.Slow Database (I'm using a free host)

Databases are the same whether paid or free. MySql is generally fast as it is file based as opposed to SQL Server. So you've got a good db.

### 5.Other Reasons

I don't think db's should be updated that often. But that's me.

## Solution?

Well, there isn't a clear cut reason, but you can do micro-optimization like use stored procedures, they are faster if you are doing the same thing over and over again.

Use parameterized query. Don't concatenate strings.

Last and most important: Think it over again, if you really need to update the db in the `Tick` event. If possible convert that into some button's `Click` event

Comment: I want to learn how these browser mmo games update their databases with thousands of players almost instantly and how all these players can play at the same time. About your answer: I think the main problem with the Tick is that when the code takes 1-2 seconds to process, the interval of the Tick becomes less accurate and I don't know what else I can use. Also I'm sure these game must be updating their databases even more often than this.